# Citing references while supplying additional information

Tags: citing

I'm trying to cite a reference as in the following picture

[image]

But all I'm getting is:

[image]

I'm using `\cite` to generate citation call-outs in an "alphabetic" style. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hi, welcome. `\cite[Proposition 1.8]{bour71}`?

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`? It has commands for this.

Comment: I tried using [Proposition 1.8] before, but it's not changing the colour of the square brackets [ and ] :\

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable code how you cite and build your bibliography. Do not forget and add one bib entry to your question!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{bb09 , Author = "Blah and Blue", year = 2009}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} for 'DarkGreen' color
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=DarkGreen]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{bb09}, \cite[Proposition~1.8]{bb09}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```